# raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'TCL_LIB (.Py para Exe)

Tags: python

Estou tentando converter um script Python para exe para rodar em maquinas Windows, tenho o seguinte codigo no setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import subprocess
import socket
import os



base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
        Executable("lista.py", base=base)
]

buildOptions = dict(
        packages = [],
        includes = ["subprocess","socket","os"],
        include_files = [
            os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Eduardo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32', 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Eduardo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32', 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        ],
        excludes = []
)




os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Eduardo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Eduardo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

setup(
    name = "ListaConfigs",
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = "Recolhe Informações do Computador",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
 )
```

Procurando por soluções encontrei os links:[Solução 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533803/keyerror-tcl-library-when-i-use-cx-freeze)  e  [Solução 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559171/pyinstaller-and-python3-6-tuple-index) 
O problema é que tanto um quanto  outro são erro. Quando tento executar o comando:

```
pyinstaller -F setup.py
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
 return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

O -F builda ele com apenas um executavel, sem os outros muitos arquivos que são gerados normalmente.

Já quando tento pelo cx_Freeze com o comando:

```
python setup.py build
```

ou
    python setup.py bdist_msi

Da o erro:

```
 raise KeyError(key) from None
 KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

Não tem pasta do python em Arquivos de Programas nem na x86. Por algum motivo foi instalado neste caminho que esta no codigo.

Não sei mais o que pode ser feito aqui.

Agradeço desde ja a atenção

**OBS.: Dei uma pesquisada e parece que o pyinstaller ainda não é compativel com o python 3.6([Link que diz isso](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2286) então não se deveria utilizar uma versão anterior a essa para funcionar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, a versão Stable do pyinstaller é somente compatível com Python 2.7, 3.3–3.5, o Python 3.6 só é suportando na versão Development do pyinstaller, mas ainda não é um software estável.

Você pode até arriscar e baixar (e instalar manualmente) a versão não estável:

- https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/zipball/develop

Já o erro do `cx_Freeze` é porque não foi definido nas variaveis de ambiente o `TCL_LIBRARY`, você pode executar eles sem definir também, diretamente no CMD (baseado nesta [**resposta** do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706103/1518921), não sei se funciona no 3.6):

```
set TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6
set TK_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6
```

No entanto creio que seja mais prático definir no `setup.py`

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'
```